# React-Native packages in Expo issue

Tags: react-native, import, package, export, native

Hi everyone hope you guys are doing well. My question is that can I use react-native packages in my expo app or I have to must use expo packages.

**My scenario** : I have expo app and now I wanna to use file picker for the app, So can i use " **npm i react-native-document-picker** " or I must have to use " **npx expo install expo-document-picker** " ?

Hope you understand my question, I am waiting for your response, Thank you.

I am trying to solve my react-native packages issue.